# two github cli versions installed

Tags: git, github

Apparently I had github cli (further just “ghcli”) installed, but it was outdated, when I typed:

```
git --version
```

I got:

```
git version 2.39.3 (Apple Git-145)
```

so hoping that it would replace the current version, I installed ghcli via brew and it installed actually the last version, because it was showing:

```
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gh/**2.35.0**: 191 files, 44.1MB
```

but when I checked again it still wrote the same:

```
git version 2.39.3 (Apple Git-145)
```

so 1. how could I update ghcli without installing another version via brew? it is not specified here https://github.com/cli/cli#installation (which I believe is an official guide), because they mention only “Homebrew, MacPorts, Conda, Spack”
2. how can I make that new brew version my main version (I didn’t find answer here https://cli.github.com/manual/)

I tried finding answers on official websites but couldn't...

**Solution**

Git and GitHub cli are completely different things

Comment: the github cli doesn't install git - use `brew install git`

Comment: Git and GitHub's CLI are different things.

Comment: GitHub CLI provides `gh` command, only tangentially related to `git` itself. GitHub is basically one of existing options for `git` hosting - `git` is a generic storage protocol, GitHub is a brand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git and github cli are two completely different clis. git cli is to interact with a git based version control systems and it is used for local repo operations like add changes to be tracked, commit, branch, merge and to work with remote repos for push and pulls.

github cli is used to work with repositories in GitHub. Think of it as an extension of git for GitHub. You can work with github issues, branches, releases, pull requests, pretty much anything you would want to do with GitHub.

It looks like you would need both of them and may be you wanted to install GitHub cli.

To check if gh cli is installed on your machine you can run gh --version command.
To install gh cli on windows go to this link https://github.com/cli/cli/releases, download the msi and run it. But since you want to install on you would run brew install gh instead.

Comment: umm... thank you I didn't know that they are different